# CFC to feed events into jQuery FullCalendar

Tags: jquery, json, fullcalendar, coldfusion-8, cfc

I am trying to feed the events section of FullCalendar with a JSON string from a cfc. The cfc is returning data, but I cannot get the data to return in the format needed for this plugin. The calendar is not responding to the events. 
What do I need to do in setting up my cfc to return the proper format.
The JSON I am getting looks like this.

`[["id: 237","title: Robert Byrd - First Appt.","start: 2011-05-24 11:00:00.0","allDay: false"],["id:    238","title: Margie Hambro - First Appt.","start: 2011-05-14 08:00:00.0","allDay: false"],["id: 302","title: Judy Nichols - First Appt.","start: 2011-05-17 15:50:00.0","allDay: false"],["id: 303","title: Ben Parker - First Appt.","start: 2011-05-23 10:15:00.0","allDay: false"],["id: 304","title: Robert Lentz - First Appt.","start: 2011-05-24 11:25:00.0","allDay: false"]]`

```
<cffunction name="getLeadAppointments" access="remote" returnformat="json" returntype="any">
<cfargument name="start" type="any" required="true" default="">
<cfargument name="end" type="any" required="true" default=""> 
<!--- Get data --->
<cfquery name="data" datasource="#VARIABLES.dsn#">
SELECT  LS.LeadSched_ID AS id, 
LTRIM(COALESCE (CM.Contact_FName, '') + ' ' + COALESCE (CM.Contact_LName, '') + ' - ' + LD.DevType_Desc) AS event,
LS.LeadSched_TargetDate AS Start, 
LS.LeadSched_ActualDate
FROM    ...
Where   convert(varchar(25), LS.LeadSched_TargetDate) BETWEEN #dateAdd("s", ARGUMENTS.start, "01/01/1970")# AND #dateAdd("s", ARGUMENTS.end, "01/01/1970")#
</cfquery>

<cfsilent>
<cfset calEvents = ArrayNew(2)>
<cfoutput query="data">
<cfset calEvents[#currentRow#][1] = 'id: #data.id#'>
<cfset calEvents[#currentRow#][2] = 'title: #data.event#'>
<cfset calEvents[#currentRow#][3] = 'start: #data.start#'>
<cfset calEvents[#currentRow#][4] = 'allDay: false'>
</cfoutput>
<cfset calData = SerializeJSON(data)>
</cfsilent>

<cfreturn calEvents>
</cffunction>
```

Comment: Format your post please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a guess, but I strongly suspect that your client code wants something that looks more like this:

```
[{"id": "237","title": "Robert Byrd - First Appt.","start": "2011-05-24 11:00:00.0","allDay": false}, ...]
```

Note that the entries in the outer array are changed here from arrays of strings (as you have) into objects, and that your original strings have been split into two (excepting the boolean property at the end, "allDay", which is given the JSON native boolean `false`).

Comment: Yes that is what the client side is looking for. I can't figure out how to get that from the cfc.

Comment: OK well I'm afraid I can't help you with that part.  I don't really even know what a "cfc" is :-(  Is this a component that you wrote, or are you just trying to use some off-the-shelf code?

Comment: cfc is a coldfusion component, the data is returned by query in a named function inside the component. I have used cfc's a lot, but this is my first time writing one to feed a jquery plugin like this.

Comment: So change your CFC to return an array of structs instead. If you don't know how to use structs, check the docs, it's pretty simple.

Comment: Well, instead of having it output the name/value pairs as concatenated strings, it could output them in the proper object notation form: `"name": value`.

Comment: That was the answer, converting it to an array of structures was the step I was missing.

Comment: @CF Jedi Master Your comment was exactly what I needed to get the calendar to pull events from the database. This was a life saver, on a major project with a looming deadline. If you could help us with snippet or a pointer on getting the data updated after a dragdrop or resize event we would be happy to take care of a couple items on your wishlist. 
We think it is a matter of having the javascript call a cfc but, with our project timeline getting close, being sure would be worth it to us.

Answer (score 0):

Have you specified JSON as the returnformat in your cffunction?

`<cffunction name="myCoolFunction" returnformat="JSON" ... >`

It would help to debug further if you could post the cffunction itself, rather than just the results from it.

Comment: <cffunction name="getLeadAppointments" access="remote" returnformat="json" returntype="any">
<cfargument name="start" type="any" required="true" default="">
<cfargument name="end" type="any" required="true" default=""> 
  <!--- Get data --->
<cfquery name="data" datasource="#VARIABLES.dsn#">
SELECT LS.LeadSched_ID AS id, 
LTRIM(COALESCE (CM.Contact_FName, '') + ' ' + COALESCE (CM.Contact_LName, '') + ' - ' + LD.DevType_Desc) AS event,
LS.LeadSched_TargetDate AS Start, 
LS.LeadSched_ActualDate

Comment: <cfoutput query="data">
<cfset calEvents[#currentRow#][1] = 'id: #data.id#'>
<cfset calEvents[#currentRow#][2] = 'title: #data.event#'>
<cfset calEvents[#currentRow#][3] = 'start: #data.start#'>
<cfset calEvents[#currentRow#][4] = 'allDay: false'>
</cfoutput>
<cfset calData = SerializeJSON(data)>
</cfsilent>
<cfreturn calEvents>
</cffunction>

Comment: Could you possibly edit your original post, inserting the code above... and formatting it properly (either indent 4 spaces in, or enclose with ` character (top left of the keyboard)).  Would make it easier to follow.